# Incremental build with maven@3.3.3 in multi module project

Tags: maven

I can't find a definite answer on this, I have tried a number of extensions but none seem to work.  I have also tried the checkbox in jenkins "Incremental Build" but not working either.

I have a multi module project and a CI server running Jenkins.

There are many modules that make up the project.  When I checkin code I want only the changed code to "build/test/deploy" and any other projects that depend on this code.

Is this possible without a third party plugin?  If not, is there a third party plugin that will make this work?

From my research this seems to have been supported at some point but not with maven 3.

Comment: Perhaps, you are seeing the MCOMPILER-205 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-205) bug? Can you try the latest Maven installation?

Comment: It's more the tests that are the problem, not compilation.